# Como fazer o browser relembrar duas senhas diferentes (dois forms distintos) para um mesmo site (domínio)?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, senhas

Tenho em uma aplicação web que, de forma convencional, solicita um usuário e senha para efetuar login no sistema.

Este usuário e senha estão encapsulados em um form (exemplo simplificado):

```
<form id="formLogin">
    <input type="text" id="usuarioLogin"></input>
    <input type="password" id="senhaLogin"></input>
</form>
```

Agora dentro da aplicação tenho um outro form que solicita uma credencial diferente, para um procedimento específico. O form é muito similar, porém notem que os id's são diferentes:

```
<form id="formCredencialEspecial">
    <input type="text" id="usuarioCredencial"></input>
    <input type="password" id="senhaCredencial"></input>
</form>
```

Resultado: O browser relembra a senha do login, embora trate-se de uma outra senha. O usuário pode alterar a senha e validar a credencial especial, mas isto torna a salvar uma senha que agora passa a ser inválida para o login (primeiro form).

Há como dizer ao browser que estes forms se tratam de credenciais diferentes, e devem ser armazenados como senhas distintas?

Observações:

- Estas páginas web compõe uma SPA (desenvolvido em [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/)), e estão dentro de um mesmo domínio E recurso HTTP;
- O motivo de solicitar uma segunda credencial não está em debate nesta questão.

Comment: Porque não armazena em cookies as duas?

Comment: nunca precisei fazer isso, mas acho  que depende do navegador, cada um lida com isso do seu jeito.

Comment: @Miguel - já faço isso. O primeiro login o usuário acaba informando uma vez só. A segunda credencial é informada sempre, que por fim é a senha que realmente fica salva pelo navegador. Neste caso, somente no primeiro acesso que ocorre esta situação. Ainda assim, julgo ser um caso curioso que vale a pergunta.